# Use a gamepad as joystick in Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, xorg, game-controller

Recently I discovered my game pad was acting like the mouse in my Linux Mint 13 Maya. It was really cool feature but It's not what I need all the time.

[I fixed it over at Ask Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33672/joystick-acts-as-mouse-wont-stop)

Anyway, Sometimes I just want to play Mupen64Plus so I was wondering if there's a way to turn on/off the `xserver-xorg-input-joystick` package. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use `xinput float` to detach it from the virtual core pointer.